# How to search file contents on iOS?

Tags: ios, spotlight, search, file

Is it even possible? Like, for example, list all php files that contain the word “filter”?

Answer (score 2):

Store your files in the [files app on iOS and iPadOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109) and then the contents are indexed. Similar to macOS, once you search for a string, you can restrict it to the current folder if desired.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102570
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/102440

Search works for me on local files, iCloud files and just ad described above by Apple support pages. The search works for content and for name.

Here is what that looks like:

[image: Files search by content]

The source is this screenplay: http://dailyscript.com/scripts/arrival.pdf

The first copy is still in "Downloads" and I duplicated it in files and then moved it to "On My iPhone" to test both an iCloud synchronized and backed location of the file as well as local only storage. This works for many other names and file types / text / PDF and more for me (choosing other names in the screenplay or other search terms that have zero hits for file names and only hits for file content).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? How do I store them and then search?

Comment: @CainNuke Actually, when you search for something, you should see an option to search "For document titles", which will restrict the search criteria. By default, it searches for file contents.

Comment: So th option doesnt work for local files? Also, i cant find that option “for socument titles”. Can i see a screenshot please?

Comment: It works on my local files. I don’t my screenshots would look different than the Apple support pages. Maybe you need to work with Apple support and troubleshoot? Restart, try different files like pdf and plain text and update your question with some more details, @CainNuke ?

Comment: I tried the support pages but they have no screenshots of search by content, only search by name.

Comment: It's the same field @CainNuke . Everything is searched / name and content and it's clear in this case the Chiang didn't match the file name...

Comment: Then maybe it wont look inside php files or so after all…